# Gaussian noise model derivation

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, maximum-likelihood

I have the following linear regression model, $y = f(x;w) + n$, where $y$ is the vector of true labels, $x$ is the observed data, $f(x;w) = w^Tx$, and $n$ ~ $N(0, \sigma^2)$ is the noise.  Why then does $p(y|x;w) = N(w^Tx;\sigma^2)$ (taken from page 12 of these notes: http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf)?  Could someone please derive this for me?

Comment: Are you aware that adding a constant $\mu$ to a Normal$(0,\sigma^2)$ variable gives a Normal$(\mu,\sigma^2)$ variable?

Comment: Why is this true?

Comment: For many people, it's the *definition.* One first defines a Normal$(0,1)$ variable (its probability density at any number $x$ is proportional to $\exp(-x^2/2)$) [and then defines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#General_normal_distribution) a Normal$(\mu,\sigma^2)$ variable to be a Normal$(0,1)$ variable that has been multiplied by $\sigma$ and had $\mu$ added to it. Evidently that is not your definition, so what is your definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think whuber boils the questions down to its essentials with

> adding a constant $μ$ to a Normal$(0,σ^2)$ variable gives a Normal$(μ,σ^2)$ variable

So how do we know this is true? How we show that depends on what you're prepared to start with. To talk about the normal *at all* we must begin with some kind of definition, so it depends on what you define the general normal to be. (As whuber points out, Wikipedia defines $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ as a scaled, shifted standard normal, from which the pdf can be derived).

We can go the other way; we could begin with say a $N(0,\sigma^2)$ (your $n$ variable) and investigate the effect of adding $\mu$ to it. Here's the density of $n$:

$$\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\, e^{-\frac{n^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$$

Let $Y=n+\mu$.

Now, how do we work out the density of the transformed (shifted) random variable? Again, it depends on what you're prepared to assume. It can be done from first principles ($F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(n+\mu\leq y)=P(n\leq y-\mu)=F_n(y-\mu)$ and then differentiate $F_Y(y)$ to obtain the density $f_Y(y)$).

Or we could use the transformation result $f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|$

So $n=Y-\mu$, hence $g=y-\mu$ and $dy = dn$

Hence $f_Y(y)=f_n(y-\mu).|1|$

$$=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\, e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$$

which is a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Comment: +1 I would like to suggest that a simpler and fully general way to show the effect of an affine transformation would be to contemplate the CDF rather than the PDF: when $Y=\sigma X+\mu$ (with $\sigma\gt 0$), then $F_Y(x)={\Pr}(Y\le x)={\Pr}(X\le (x-\mu)/\sigma)$, whence each "$x$" in the PDF (if it exists) must be replaced by "$(x-\mu)/\sigma$" and the $dx$ (which is implicitly in the PDF) must be replaced by $d((x-\mu)/\sigma)=dx/\sigma$. This doesn't really even require any knowledge of Calculus, but only of how to obtain slopes of lines.

Comment: Why is $N(w^Tx, \sigma^2)$ then set equal to $p(y|x;w)$?  It seems just as reasonable to let $p(y,x;w) = N(w^Tx, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: @whuber indeed so; via CDFs in essentially the way you did it is the way I prefer to look at it. I guessed that since the fact wasn't immediately obvious to the OP, that such an explanation might carry less impact than the pdf version that essentially derives from it.

Comment: @eric throughout the calculation, we're conditioning on $x$. The idea is to model the conditional expectation (we don't necessarily know the *distribution* of $x$, only the values we have -- it may not even be a random variable; it might be experimentally controlled, for example).

Answer (score 2):

To complement what *whuber* said in  the comments. You can do some simple manipulations to derive the distribution of $y^{(i)}$. In the regression equation:

$$y^{(i)} = \theta^T x^{(i)} + \epsilon^{(i)}$$

We isolate $\epsilon^{(i)} $ and than replace it in the density formula:

$$p(\epsilon^{(i)}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}exp{\left(-\frac{(\epsilon^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)} $$

$$p(y^{(i)} - \theta^T x^{(i)}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}exp{\left(-\frac{(y^{(i)} - \theta^T x^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)} $$

Then we rewrite the probability term in a more convenient way, considering $\theta$ as a fixed parameter and $x^{(i)}$ as a given variable. So

$$p(y^{(i)}| x^{(i)}; \theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}exp{\left(-\frac{(y^{(i)} - \theta^T x^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)} $$

Comment: +1 yours posted when I was almost finished composing mine. I guess mine shows some details the OP might seek, so I'll leave it there for now.

Comment: In your final equation, why is it correct to assume that $x^{(i)}$ is fixed?  It seems more appropriate to define $p(y^{(i)}, x^{(i)};\theta) = N(\theta^Tx, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: In order to write $y^{(i)} = \theta^T x^{(i)} + \epsilon^{(i)}$ you assumed that $x$ was your predictor variable (called the "input" variable in the notes), thus by definition it is a given variable, you know its value.

Comment: Furthermore, you're not picking randomly a $(x, y)$ pair and measuring its probability. You're choosing instead a $x$ and then measuring the probability of the response variable $y$ taking a particular value.